# Field measurements in QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-measurements

If I understand it correctly, QFT assigns a field operator to every point in space. For a free scalar field:
$$ \hat{\phi}(\mathbf{x},t)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\mathbf{p}}}} \left[\hat{a}_{\mathbf{p}} 
\exp(-i\omega_{\mathbf{p}}t+i{\mathbf{p}}\cdot\mathbf{x}) + \hat{a}_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} 
\exp(i\omega_{\mathbf{p}}t-i{\mathbf{p}}\cdot\mathbf{x})\right] . $$

This operator is Hermitian, so it corresponds to an observable (which makes sense, as it should be possible to measure the "strength" of the field at every point). A given quantum state can be represented as a superposition of the field operator eigenstates, and measuring the field at point $x$ should collapse the state to one of these eigenstates. My question is: what would happen if the field is measured simultaneously at two different points, $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$? The field operators at these points are different (since they depend on $x$), so the eigenstate decompositions are different. Which eigenstate could the quantum state collapse to, if there are no common eigenstates between the operators at $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$?

Comment: It's EPR paradox!

Comment: The field operators at different spatial points commute, so actually there exists a common eigenstate decomposition.  You can diagonalize the field operators at all spatial points simulataneously. The resulting eigenstates are the "field" states |\phi>. See keyword "wavefunctional."

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now! I didn't realize there are common eigenstates.